# Can mantras help transfer energy miraculously to a person or object?

Tags: mantras, kali-yuga, guru, weapon, spiritual-level

By means of a secret Mantra or formula a spiritual guru or God when pleased can donate or transfer spiritual energy to others... for example at the end of an arduous dedicated work or tapas to a devotee as a boon.

EDIT 1:

It is possible to believe in it without remaining skeptic. Sri Ramakrishna Paramahansa took upon himself (He received, not transmitted a malady, may be cancer, from a devotee that he suffered at his Samadhi time. So also Sai Baba of Shirdi showed his devotees and even disbelievers many instances of such miracles. He declared the Spiritual energy can be effectively transferred, responding where trust and belief are present even after SaiBaba ceased to mortally exist. In the Thyagaraja movie overflowing energy of the musician could effectively cure the sick by his prayer and sympathetic wishes. So did Jesus of Nazereth..it seems to be a phenomenon of pure spirit and associated with no faith in particular.

As for power delivery through Astras a Mantra is invoked into an arrow before releasing the bow to shoot in war.. for spreading water or fire as a missile or for killing enemies in combat is well  known in mythology. Sitha matha threatened to slay Ravana if he violated while captive just using a blade of grass.

The energy can be directed to an Astra or another person. It is activated by the recipient when the Mantra is invoked. The Source/Giver repeatedly transfers or transmits spiritual energy for a good cause or destruction in war as may be intended or desired.

Have such miraculous events been in evidence in recent times? Is it a form of telepathy? For example during Maha Kumbh Mela by some Yogis? Or is such power lost out in the Kali Yuga?

Comment: astra vidyas no longer exist in the earthly realm in kali yuga. Also wrong tag.

Comment: Every competent Guru transfers spiritual shakti to his disciples during mantra initiation. It is not anything special.

Comment: But effects of such transfer so visible, dynamic, verifiable is something quite special.

Comment: No astras at there in kaliyug, only god's name is there. Chant god's name and forget about astras which is beyond anyone's capacity to know or find. Also gods have not given any knowledge to any one in kaliyug even if he or she is realised. So don't waste time and chant god's name

Comment: @Narasimham:   Good question.

Comment: "Have such miraculous events been in evidence in recent times" no not a single one unfortenately.

Answer (score 1):

The question is: ***Can mantras help transfer energy miraculously to a person or object?***

It was also queried in Edited version of the question, as follows:

> The Source/Giver repeatedly transfers or transmits spiritual energy
>   for a good cause or destruction in war as may be intended or desired.
>
> Have such miraculous events been in evidence in recent times? Is it a
>   form of telepathy?

---

It can happen.  However, the **secret does not lie in the mantra** that is recited, **but in the DIVINE will of the Sage,** who transmits his/her spiritual energy.

When the sage says **let a word be uttered** for achieving the results, it works.  If the sage says **let an oil be used** for achieving the results, it works.

---

Sri Lahiri Mahasaya ordered [to use castor oil](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Autobiography_of_a_Yogi/Chapter_32), to revive a dead person.

Sri Swamy Samarth ordered to [utter the name](https://swamisamarth.com/one-who-is-protected-by-god/) to revive a dead person.

The above incidents occurred in the recent past.

Comment: So in a blessing or curse (positive or negative will/ intent)  a packet of will is delivered by the sender orally or by mind force and the  receiver has no choice in  its reception modality but  has to unpack it to activate its effect on him/her self, right?

Comment: Partially yes,  in respect of a mediator.   If the DIVINE WILL is directed against the person of his choice by the sage,  no further need of unpacking as happened in the case of Swami Vivekananda from Sri Ramakrishna @Narasiham

Comment: As those are speculations, there is no evidence of such powers. If you remember https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Million_Dollar_Paranormal_Challenge no one did ever demonstrate in severe and strictly scientific observance such paranormal things. I know the magical thinking of siddhis and so on, coming from so far Atharva Veda, but in reality those  things never existed. It is such a poor thinking which is also responsible for lack of evolution in some other societies (including Hinduism and some other). Let me name those things as "naive" and magic thinking, which is away from every yoga aim.

Comment: I will give another approach: if Shri Vidya gives wealth, prosperity and so on, start thinking about such named "gurus" which still ask for material possessions and money from their adepts. So, the question is: shall we trust such persons which pretend they have achieve siddhis in one particular mantra but in fact they are poor? Just a fact, which no one can deny. If some guru tells me he has attained siddhi in a mantra, I ask him to prove in reality all the things that siddhi is told to give. All those stories of reviving dead etc are just magical thinking and a bad folklore. This is the true

Comment: With due respect, Babaji is just an invented prototype influenced by Christianity. The portrait and all magical story around him was used by Yukteshwar, Yogananda to trick and make hindus beliefs more acceptable by others (including westerns). Same model was followed by Vivekananda, in other words, but the realm of such distributions of "folklore" is to make naive thinking believe in "it". But well, not everybody needs to believe in  such magical things, so is not subject of more explanations.

Comment: srimannarayana k v with due respect, peoples believe "When the sage says let a word be uttered for achieving the results, it works. If the sage says let an oil be used for achieving the results, it works." This does not mean something really works at all. It is magical thinking.

Comment: I can understand your feelings.  And, I don't want to argue in this regard, as this topic can not be understood with arguments.  The main problem with the SPIRITUAL  issues is, majority of the so called SPIRITUAL gurus are good at showing off but very bad in proving in what they state.  This chaotic situation created by majority of fake gurus is hiding the state of true SPIRITUAL gurus.  Anyways, as I had stated above, I am not here to prove my point by arguments.  Thanks for sharing your opinion. @user3344236